# Accessing ViewController's variables through another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, null, var

On my iOS app written in Swift, I have a variable which is initialized on `FirstViewController.swift`.
I want to assign its value to a label on `SecondViewController.swift`.

At first I've tried to do it like this on `SecondViewController.swift`:

```
var firstViewController: FirstViewController = FirstViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
var name = firstViewController.name
```

After the didn't work, I tried to do it using a `struct`:

```
// FirstViewController.swift
struct GlobalVariables {
    var name: String = "test"
}

// SecondViewController.swift
var name = FirstViewController.GlobalVariables.name
```

But that didn't work either. After both methods I'm printing the new variable to the console and assign its value to the label, but all I see is nothing on the label and `nil` on the console.

Can you please help me with that? How can I access to a variable on `FirstViewController.swift` through `SecondViewController.swift`?

Comment: See [How to pass data between view-controllers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjClYLhq9TTAhVpzVQKHSkPBW0QtwIILTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DguSYMPaXLaw&usg=AFQjCNGoLzd4q-_7UApdlFUBACTmk_lf5w&sig2=EqdqsRUhyF4IUO8bbLRCFQ)

Comment: What is the context of trying to share this info? Are you performing a segue? Are both VC instantiated?

Comment: @DonovanKing I'm doing a segue from `FirstViewController.swift` to `SecondViewController.swift` using a button. I don't want to pass the variable. I need the variable to be available from all ViewControllers without passing it

Comment: You'd probably want to create a model object (or a struct) to hold this piece of data and access it by the two ViewControllers.

Comment: @SimpleBeat I've already tried to use a struct

Comment: @IdoNaveh You did use a struct in your `FirstViewController.swift`, but I am thinking more of a separate file for all the data (label values you want to access by `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`), for example `Model.swift`. If you use a struct you don't even need initializers for that! Just a couple of `get`/`set` methods. Then you can modify that value by `FirstViewController`, and after a segue read the updated value by `SecondViewController`.

Comment: @SimpleBeat Could you please instruct me how? I'm new to iOS development

Comment: @IdoNaveh - if you ***really*** want to use access a variable (or a bunch of variables) from *"all ViewControllers without passing it"* then what you need to search for is `swift global variables` and/or `swift singletons`. A quick read through a couple articles and you'll have a much better understanding of "access a variable on..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass arguments between View Controllers, you can use segues.

First you have the variable in FirstViewController

```
FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var name: String = "test"
    ...
}
```

Then you have a variable of the same type in SecondViewController

```
SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var name: String = ""
    ...
}
```

To move from FirstViewController, you use a programmatic segue.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Indentifier", sender: nil)
```

Then, in FirstViewController, define prepareForSegue:sender.
You get a reference to the destination view controller, then set the variable to the one from sending view controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    vc.name = name
}
```

EDIT:
If you need it to be accessible in all view controllers, define a Global class. You stated in your question you tried a struct. Instead, try static variables

```
class Global {   
    static var name: String?
}
```

EDIT 2:
Another way to have global variables is with a singleton class

```
class Global {
     static let sharedInstance = Global()
     var name: String?
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Look at the comments. I need to be accessible from any ViewController. Not just this one

Comment: @IdoNaveh: If the variable is a class you're only passing a reference which means both VCs will be pointing to the same instance. Is there a particular reason you have not to pass a reference? You really shouldn't be pollution the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a barebones idea of how to do it with a separate file to hold data (values) for your labels to display. *Disclaimer: it might not be the best idea (you probably don't want to bind your ViewControllers to this single data file like this)*, but it should do the trick before you learn other better ways. So, here we go.

You want to use a separate file (name it for example `MyTextValuesModel.swift`) for all the values you'd like your `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` to access.

You select **File > New > File...** from the menu, and choose **Swift File**.

Then you declare your `class`:

```
import Foundation

class ValuesForLabels {
    var textForLabel1 = "Label1"
    var textForLabel2 = "Label2"
    var textForLabel3 = "Label3"
    // etc...
}
```

Now in your `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` you declare a variable to refer to this class:

```
var textsForLabels = ValuesForLabels()
```

Now you can access (read/write) the labels from any view controllers like this:

```
textsForLabels.textForLabel1 = "NewLabel1Text" 
// you've just set a new value for Label1

label1.text = textsForLabels.textForLabel1
// your label1 text is now set to textForLabel1
```

If you'd want to access label values from another view controller, add a new variable to your new view controller to reference the labels.

Comment: I have just tried it, but I keep on getting nil value from these variables